# Flag Query PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have that

**JavaScript**

```
flagQuery = session.reponseText;
alert(flagQuery);
flagQuery = JSON.parse(flagQuery);
contentElt.innerHTML = "valeur FLAG" + flagQuery;
```

My javascript must receive a flag sent from php.

The code above is the treatment of flag when it is received.

In my php I declare the variable flag to true.
I want to treat this with Ajax, if it's possible.
I don't know what to add in the PHP to get the flag in JavaScript?

I should prefer not to have to overload my code with a jQuery bookshop that I will use it for half a score line of code.

Comment: do you have anything already on Javascript side responsible for *receiving the data*? Do you want to use an Ajax request? Do you want to write the value into the document when it's delivered to clients? Please clarify your question in that regard. Because on the php side, a simple output script (something like `<?php echo $flag; ?>`) can be enough...?

Comment: no, I don't have anything like this. Yes, I want to use Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume want to access php value through ajax request. And you can do that liek below;

**PHP:** flag.php

```
<?php

$flag = "Your flag value";

echo $flag;
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "flag.php",
    type: "get",
    success: function(data){
        alert("Flag value is: " + data);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("Error occured!");
    }
});
```

**Pure JS:**

```
<script>
    function getFlagValue() {
        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET","flag.php",true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with jQuery

Comment: Yes, it is not tagged, but, my aim is suggesting jQuery to user. I have gave just an example how to do it

Comment: It's possible to do the same thing without the jQuery? I should prefer not to have to overload my code with a bookshop that I will use it for half a score line of code.

Comment: tanks, It's exactly what I want!

Comment: Don't you need to set the header to `json/application` in PHP first? Just wondering, that's how I usually do it.

Comment: If you are returning just string, in your case you are returning string, you don't need. However, If you want to return a json obejct converted from array, you can set header as you said. According to me, if you always return json, set your header. It would be better

Comment: it's already set. I always set the header for various case. Just in case!

Answer (score 0):

**Hello. Try this and see if it's you need.**

```
//PHP File
<?php
    echo json_encode(array("one","two"));
?>



//Js File
$.get("page.php", function(data){
 alert(data)
})
```